# How do I make loop with a changed data name in R

Tags: r, loops

I would like to make a loop function in R like this:

```
threshold_month = 3
dta_3 <- dta_fin %>%
  filter(month < threshold_month)

threshold_month = 6
dta_6 <- dta_fin %>%
  filter(month < threshold_month)

threshold_month = 9
dta_9 <- dta_fin %>%
  filter(month < threshold_month)
```

How do I make loop function using the threshold value 3, 6, and 9..?

Comment: You can use the `assign` function in a loop - check `assign(paste0("dta_", 3), filter(dta_fin, month < 3))`

Comment: Could you give more detail advice ?....

Comment: I posted it as answer as it needed a code block. I recommend checking the `?assign` help page (especially the examples) to understand how it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot to you!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
for (threshold_month in c(3, 6, 9)) {
    assign(paste0("dta_", threshold_month), filter(dta_fin, month < threshold_month))
}
```